# SharePoint 2019 Suitebar is disappear and unable to correct it back

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

We are just setup a SharePoint Server 2019 and created several site collections. We first remove the top left element of the suite bar in .css or .js. I am not sure where did I remove the suite bar.

However, we would like to bring it back to all site collections. I tried to edit the SuiteNav.CSS COREV15.CSS and the master page css file, but no luck to bring it back (Please refer to the Reference Image).

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qudPk.jpg)

I use f12 to check the class and found this part is totally missing from my site collection.

```
<div class="o365cs-nav-topItem o365cs-nav-o365Branding o365cs-rsp-tn-hideIfAffordanceOn"><a class="o365button o365cs-nav-appTitle o365cs-topnavText" role="heading" href="https://<spsite>/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx" id="Sites_BrandBar" aria-label="SharePoint"><span class="o365cs-nav-brandingText">SharePoint</span></a></div>
```

Can someone let me know how to fix it or how to reset the suite bar setting/config file to default. Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0):

You can find the CSS attribute of the corresponding element and the location of the CSS file in effect in the style window of the developer tools.
Pay special attention to：`display:none`.
[image]

[image]

If no CSS that does not display the element is not found, find all the js files that work on the current page in the developer tools.

[image]

After you find your custom js file, click to view the source code.Then you can debug the code, find out the effective code, and upload the modified code to the corresponding location.